# Year over year returns to single period returns

Tags: algorithm

Does anyone know of a quick algorithm to convert year over year returns to single period returns? Python code would be appreciated!

For reference, year over year refers to returns being calculated on an annual basis, for statistics that are reported on a higher frequency (to remove seasonality). So e.g. if total gas consumption is reported every month, the year over year return would be the percent difference between Dec 2018 and Dec 2017 and the single period return would be the difference between Dec 2018 and Nov 2018

So assuming you only have a series of YOY changes, is there a way to return monthly changes (in the above example)

tldr: I have a data series of year over year returns

ret(Jan 2017 to Jan 2018) = 1%

ret(Feb 2017 to Feb 2018) = -1.5%

ret(Mar 2017 to Mar 2018) = .5%

how do I convert it to a series of monthly returns?

ret(Jan 2017 to Feb 2017) = ?

ret(Feb 2017 to Mar 2017) = ?
...

Comment: The best you could do is an average approximation when you're talking about taking coarse data and extracting fine data. Also, have you tried asking on the money & finance stack exchange site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: *"So assuming you only have a series of YOY changes, is there a way to return monthly changes?"*

Answer: **No.**

This can be demonstrated with a simple example. Here are four sample points:

```
Jan 2017  100
Feb 2017   90
...
Jan 2018  200
Feb 2018  180
```

The single period returns are -10%, and the year over year returns are +100%.

And here's another set of samples with the same year over year returns:

```
Jan 2017  100
Feb 2017  150
...
Jan 2018  200
Feb 2018  300
```

The single period returns are +50%, and the year over year returns are +100%.

Bottom line: the year-over-year returns tell you nothing about the month-to-month returns. To compute the month-to-month returns, you would need the monthly figures for at least one of the two years, in addition to the year-over-year returns.